# Entity Framework Database First approach in Azure

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, azure, ef-database-first

I have a bunch of SQL scripts that create my database. I'd like to use the Database First approach with EF and Azure. I figured out that there are certain fields that my tables need to include:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Company
(
    [Id] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_Company_Id DEFAULT '0',
    CompanyName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_Company_Name DEFAULT '',

    -- Azure properties
    [Version] TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    [CreatedAt] DATETIMEOFFSET(7) NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedAt] DATETIMEOFFSET(7) NULL,
    [Deleted] BIT NOT NULL
)
```

I also figured out that I need certain constraints on these fields:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Company ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Company PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([Id] ASC);
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Company ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Company_CreatedAt DEFAULT CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET(7), SYSUTCDATETIME(), 0) FOR [CreatedAt]
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Company ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Company_Deleted DEFAULT 0 FOR Deleted
GO
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_Company_CreatedAt ON dbo.Company([CreatedAt] ASC)
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [TR_Company_InsertUpdateDelete] ON dbo.Company
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE AS
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.Company
            SET dbo.Company.[UpdatedAt] = CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, SYSUTCDATETIME())
            FROM INSERTED WHERE inserted.[Id] = dbo.Company.[Id]
    END
GO
```

I'm wondering if there is any documentation for that. I'm not sure if I included all fields and constraints. Also, I'm not sure if creating tables using a SQL script like the above one is a good approach for EF with Azure.

Any advice?

===UPDATED TO CLARIFY THE QUESTION===

Maybe it would be clearer to explain my question step-by-step:

- I have a bunch of SQL scripts that create database structure.
- I'd like to make the database structure usable by Azure. For example, Azure has Offline Data Sync feature that I know requires certain fields in the tables.
- Through trial and error, I have found that Azure uses certain fields (Version, CreatedAt, UpdatedAt, and Deleted) and triggers to provide its features (such as Offline Data Sync).
- I modified my SQL scripts to include this "Azure-specific" fields and triggers.

The problem is the "trial and error" part. It's just wrong to apply such an approach in production code that potentially will be used by many users. I'd like to find out what exactly Azure needs in the database. When the database is created using Code First all the "plumbing" is created by Azure. With the Database First approach, I have to create this plumbing. I'm wondering if I did not miss anything.